# Best way to obtain an object with all (or some) related entities in DDD

Tags: api, domain-driven-design, dto, gateway

We have a solution based in DDD and we want to get all the information of certain entity, including all its aggregates. For example, something like this:

[image]

Which could be the best approach to get all the information of the Order aggregate including the Buyer aggregate data?

I was thinking that using the API Gateway to get these entities and provide a DTO as a response could work, but I don't know if it would be the best practice in this case.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What's your datastore (e.g. relational DB?)? What are you concerns with the solutions you've attempted?

Comment: OK, we have two different restful APIs, one which can obtain the order information, and other that can obtain the buyer information. When we call one of this APIs, they access the information through a DbContext, each one has its own context and each context doesn't know the information stored in the other one. So, our goal is call a service (here it's the problem) that could provide the information of the main entity (e.g. Order) and all information of its related entities (e.g. Buyer), but the Order model is related to it through a property named BuyerId. Probably, we need to use a DTO.

Answer (score 0):

> So, our goal is call a service (here it's the problem) that could provide the information of the main entity (e.g. Order) and all information of its related entities (e.g. Buyer), but the Order model is related to it through a property named BuyerId.

You already know some component needs to be responsible for data aggregation. It usually boils down to deciding whether the aggregation will occur downstream (e.g. UI) or upstream (e.g. server).

If the APIs are already in place to gather the Buyer's data and the Order's data and the downstream client has the necessary correlation IDs on hand then it becomes possible for the downstream client to deal with the complexity of aggregating data. Whether this is acceptable or not is another story.

If you want to solve data aggregation issues upstream then you will most likely have two main strategies to choose from:

1. Aggregate in the application

   ```
   public OrderDetailsDto orderDetails(OrderId orderId) {
       //Repositories could be switched to remote API calls
       Order order = orderRepository.findById(orderId);
       Buyer buyer = buyerRepository.findById(order.buyerId);

       return dtoAssembler.orderDetailsFrom(order, buyer); 
   }
   ```
2. Aggregate in the database

   ```
   public OrderDetailsDto orderDetails(OrderId orderId) {
       ResultSet resultSet = orderDetailsFromDb(orderId);

       return dtoAssembler.orderDetailsFrom(resultSet);
   }
   ```

> Probably, we need to use a DTO

As you can see, both implementations could return the same DTO. Using explicit DTOs is a very useful and popular approach to deal with contract & serialization issues. How data is mapped into such DTOs is completely up to you and there are a multitude of implementation strategies.